# Trouble using stock EPS images

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, gradient, stock-images

I'm using adobe illustrator, and I can't seem to use a stock eps file we purchased. If I remove the illustrated 'glow' elements from their original background, they turn black. What do I need to adjust/change, so that they fade to transparent when I move them to my own files..?

[image]

Comment: What color mode are you working in and what is the color mode of the stock eps file?

Comment: At a guess, the original is using blending modes on either a group or layer and you're copying the objects lower down so you aren't copying the blending modes. Just a guess though.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any sort of alpha effect being used in the file?

You could put the elements into a different blending mode such as add or screen and that should remove the black as well.